# MongoDB деградирует в скорости при большом количестве записей

Tags: mongodb, логирование, mongoose, highload

Пишу логи в MongoDB. Пока коллекция пустая (count<10000000) - всё быстро пишется и удаляется (если надо почистить старое).
По достижению 100млн записей (а такое может поступить в базу за месяц) СУБД резко деградирует и не может делать 5000-7000 записей в секунду, как раньше.
Поля записей:

```
user_id (Int,indexed), action_code(Int), action_message(String), date(Int,indexed timestamp).
```

В настройках монги WiredTiger'у выделено 3гб в кэш, данные и индексы не сжимаются для снятия лишней нагрузки с процессора. Размеры буферов увеличены, дескрипторы и т.д. были настроены по мануалам из сети.

Конфиг Железа: 4*3,4GHz (откушены у Core I7 4770), 6GB RAM, 100GB HDD.

Запросы типа

```
 .find({user_id:1234567, date:{$gt:1510304523,$lt:1510308736}}})
```

могут выполняться десятки секунд, хотя поиск выполняется только по индексированным полям.
Да и сама запись в БД падает до 2500 записей в секунду, от чего страдает сторонний сервис, который накапливает в итоге логи у себя в буфере, переполняется и дохнет.

Размеры одной записи примерно 64 байта.

Что я делаю не так? Люди работают с базами 50, 100, 200гб и норм. А у меня достигает 15-20гб (не сжатая) и начинает буксовать.

Please, show me right way.